# Azure Active Directory SSO

Tags: active-directory, azure

I am trying to add SAML SSO for Azure AD. If I click on a Litmos App that has been set up with SAML SSO, there is an SSO option with settings.

However, if I try to create a new custom application that has been developed in house, it never gives an option to add SAML settings. (The configure menu only has two steps)

Is there a button somewhere to add SSO settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the guide below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps

The trick is to put in the name of the app once you get to the first add menu. Once you add the name of a custom app, a checkmark becomes clickable. Clicking the checkmark will generate the app.

Once generated, there will be a big green button to configure SSO after generation. SAML settings can be configured in those options.